# Download apk file from S3 using DownloadManager

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to download a file from an S3 bucket using Android's DownloadManager?

I can currently download an apk file from Dropbox doing this:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

request.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
request.setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");

final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
final long id = manager.enqueue(request);
```

Now what I want to do is replace "url" with my Amazon URL. When I do this, the download just stays at 0% and just gets stuck there.

Is there any way to do this?

By the way, the Amazon URL I pass in contains the `AWSAccessKeyId`, `Expires`, and `Signature` parameters. The url looks like this:

```
https://bucket-name.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/app/apk/22/app.apk?AWSAccessKeyId=""&Expires=""&Signature=""
```

Comment: Have you tried plain HTTP instead of HTTPS? Have you tried accessing the URL in a Web browser app on the device or emulator that you are testing on? Have you tried a URL that is for a public resource (i.e., one that does not require any of those query parameters)? Those are just some ideas to perhaps narrow the problem down a bit.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just tried some of things you suggested. The download works if I click the option "make public" on the file in my S3 bucket. That removes the need for the parameters. So I'm assuming the problem is somehow related to my AWS credentials? The file does download in my browser on my computer though with the credentials in the link.

Comment: "So I'm assuming the problem is somehow related to my AWS credentials?" -- I have never tried a URL with query parameters with `DownloadManager`. I would *think* that `DownloadManager` would support it. Take a peek at the parsed `Uri` and stuff like `getQuery()` or `getQueryParameters()` and make sure that your values are not getting scrambled somewhere along the way.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok I just looked at the parsed Uri and everything in getQueryParamters() and getQuery() and everything seems to be fine. The weird thing is that I never get an error or anything from DownloadManager. It just hangs. I would think I'd get something back like a 401 or 403 error or something.

Comment: If you can find some other URL for a download that involves query parameters (not S3), give it a whirl. If it fails, then `DownloadManager` perhaps has a limitation on query parameters. If it succeeds, then something in the handshaking between `DownloadManager` and S3 involving those query parameters is the culprit, though I don't really know where you'd go from there.

Comment: For the record, `DownloadManager` supports query strings, at least in its latest incarnation (API 23) !

Comment: I am facing similar issue. I don't have any request header, still download is not working. I tried with retrofit, there i had to verify hostname, for api to work. How to achieve this?

Comment: @Jai I am facing same issue too. Do you fix it now?

Comment: Using retrofit trust manager, I was able to make some progress. But, trusting all certificate didn't felt like a good idea, so we made some changes to s3 url itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it fails is because you set the `Content-Type` header. This header isn't needed for HTTP download. However, once set, it has to part of the signature in the presigned URL, as required by AWS S3. Or else you will see 403 Forbidden - `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error.

The quick solution is to remove the `Content-Type` header.

```
request.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

Another solution is to generate a presigned URL with headers you need. Say you really want to set content type, you can add it to GeneratePresignedUrlRequest and then create an URL from it.

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest request = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucket, key);
request.setContentType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(request);
```

See [AmazonS3.generatePresignedUrl(GeneratePresignedUrlRequest)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#generatePresignedUrl(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GeneratePresignedUrlRequest)) for more details.

Comment: Wow. Thanks this worked. You said this is the "quick" solution. Are there any problems associated with this solution I should look out for? Is there a better "longer" solution? I don't have a problem with your solution, but just wondering if there's anything I should be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Hello You can use the following header to get the apk file in request.

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:819457
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
```